# Why animator smoothes dynamic updates, or how to make pacman drink beer

Tags: dynamic, animation

How could I make a pacman drink beer in Mathematica?
This is what I have so far

```
pacman[xposFun_, angleFun_] := {Yellow, 
   Disk[{Dynamic@xposFun[Clock[{0, Infinity}]], 0`}, 1`, 
    Dynamic[{Pi/6 Abs@Sin[2 Pi Clock[]], 
       angleFun[Clock[{0, Infinity}]]} /. {val_, ang_} :> {val + ang, 
        2 Pi - val}]]};

burp := Quiet@EmitSound@ListPlay@Upsample[ConstantArray[1, 80], 200]

xpos[t_] := \[Piecewise] {
    {5 t, 0 < t < 3},
    {15, t >= 3},
    {0, True}
   };

angle[t_] := \[Piecewise] {
   {0, 0 < t < 3},
   {Pi/4 (t - 3), 3 < t < 4.8},
   {Pi/4 (4.8 - 3), t > 4.8}
  }

angleBeer[t_] := \[Piecewise] {
   {0, 0 < t < 3.5},
   {Pi/4 (t - 3.5), 3.5 < t < 5.3},
   {Pi/4 (5.3 - 3.5), t > 5.3}
  }

beer[filling_] := {{Opacity[0.2], EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Gray]], 
    Polygon[{{0`, 0`}, {1`, 0`}, {1.2, 1.5}, {-0.2, 1.5}}]},
   Opacity[0.8], filling, EdgeForm[Directive[White, Thickness[0.01]]],
    Scale[{Polygon[{{0`, 0`}, {1`, 0`}, {1.2, 1.3}, {-0.2, 1.3}}],
     White, 
     Polygon[{{-0.2, 1.3}, {1.2, 1.3}, {1.3, 1.6}, {-0.3, 1.6}}]}, 
    0.9],
   {Opacity[0.], EdgeForm[Directive[Gray, Thickness[0.01]]], 
    Disk[{1.1`, 0.7`}, 0.3, {-Pi/2 - 0.2, Pi/2 - 0.2}]}};

Graphics[{pacman[xpos, angle], 
  Translate[
   Rotate[beer[
     Dynamic[If[Clock[{0, 5.4}, 5.4, 1] < 5.4, Darker@Yellow, 
       If[Clock[{0, 7.4, 1}, 7.4, 1] == 7.4, Refresh[burp, None]]; 
       Opacity[0.]]]], 
    Dynamic@angleBeer[Clock[{0, Infinity}]]], {16, -0.2}]}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-1.2, 2}}, Background -> Black]

 Animator@Dynamic@anything
```

[image]

Now, this serves as an excuse to ask the real question. This is an issue I've also had with version 8 but that I didn't have a reproducible small code for it.
I see the dynamic animation is choppy but it gets fixed while any `Animator` is running on display dynamically updating something, like the `Animator@Dynamic@anything` that the code above displays after the pacman.
For testing, you can get the animation to restart, by copying and pasting the cell in the same place. Once the pacman is moving, try starting and stopping the animator to see the difference in choppiness.

Furthermore, changing the `DynamicUpdateInterval` in the `SystemOption`s can make this improve but it's always choppier without the animator, as if without it it always missed some frames... 
Do you see this behaviour too? 
How could I tell the front end "heyy, an animation is happening even if I'm not using an animator"?

Comment: @EliLansey the "waca waca" sound would be nice :P. Any ideas how to synthesize it?

Comment: Shouldn't the beer have bubbles :)

Comment: With 8.0.4 on Max 10.6.8 I didn't notice any choppiness but got an error from `ListPlay`. What is `Upsample` -- is a V9 function?

Comment: Yes @MikeHoneychurch. it puts zeros in between the elemts of the list. As many as the second argument says

Comment: Change `Disk[{Dynamic[bla], 0}, 1, Dynamic[bla]]` in `pacman` definition to `Dynamic[Disk[{bla, 0}, 4, bla]]` seems to make it smoother on my MMA 9. Maybe when multiple `Dynamic`s are used, they compete against each other? Or MMA must choose one `Dynamic` to update for any one frame?

Comment: Rojo, please let me know if you wish me to specifically award the bounty.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard award it to Michael for his attempts, he deserves it. It was a useful bounty, 2 interesting answers, thanks!

Comment: I won't be accepting any answer for now, since I believe the real story is quite different to what's been posted. Perhaps after some more digging I'll self-answer, or perhaps some answer gets revamped, or a new one appears, who knows

Answer (score 12):

[*Edit 2*: I've added further analysis and modified some of the explanations, esp. with respect to `Refresh`.  Still far from complete, I fear.]

First of all, I find if I set `SetSystemOptions["DynamicUpdateInterval" -> 0.005]`, then I cannot perceive a difference in performance with or without the `Animator` running.  I see a very few hiccups in both scenarios, but I suspect the hiccups are due to system granularity (or too much beer).

---

On to some findings. I tested things by setting `SetSystemOptions["DynamicUpdateInterval" -> 0.5]`, which allowed me better to perceive slow versus fast.

**Hypothesis 1** - *`Animator` overrides `SystemOptions["DynamicUpdateInterval"]`*

This is obvious.  But how?

*Edit.*  `Manipulator` affects dynamic updating in a way similar to `Animator`.  If the slider is moved or animated, updating is rapid.

**Hypothesis 2 (modified)** - *`Dynamic@Refresh[..., UpdateInterval -> t]` can bypass `"DynamicUpdateInterval"`*

*Edit:*
Originally I reported `Refresh` sporadically overriding "DynamicUpdateInterval".  After further playing with various permutations, `Refresh` appears not to override "DynamicUpdateInterval", at least not consistently.  If I copy and paste two or more copies the output of

```
Dynamic@Refresh[Clock[], UpdateInterval -> 0.01]
```

I usually get rapidly updating clocks that switch between slow and rapid updating over long periods.

**Hypothesis 3** - *Clocks of the form `Clock[{0, Infinity, dt}]` behave differently than those of the form `Clock[{0, Infinity}]` or `Clock[]`*

Compare the output of the original with the following modification, with the `Animator` running:

```
pacman[xposFun_, angleFun_] := {Yellow,
 Disk[{Dynamic@xposFun[Clock[{0, Infinity, 0.01}]], 0`}, 1`,
  Dynamic[{Pi/6 Abs@Sin[2 Pi Clock[{0, Infinity, 0.01}]],
   angleFun[Clock[{0, Infinity, 0.01}]]} /. {val_, ang_} :> {val+ang, 2 Pi-val}]]}
```

In both versions, the position is updated smoothly.  But in the original code the mouth is updated every 0.5 sec., and in the above modification the mouth is updated smoothly.

Two or more clocks of the form `Clock[{0, Infinity, 0.01}]` randomly alternate between slow and rapid updating, while the other forms, such as `Clock[]`, remain slow (unless wrapped in `Refresh` as in Hyp. 2 above):

```
Dynamic@Clock[]

Dynamic@Clock[{0, Infinity, 0.01}]

Dynamic@Clock[{0, Infinity, 0.01}]
```

Another difference is that `Clock[{0, Infinity, 0.01}]` calls `Floor` and `Mod`, while the other forms of `Clock` do not.

**Hypothesis 4** - *The system updates dynamic outputs ahead of schedule when convenient*

I vaguely mean that for some reason updating the position of `pacman` is linked with updating the `Animator`, perhaps because of some connection to `Clock`.

@Rojo noticed that in the second case below, the animator does not cause `Clock[{0, Infinity, 0.01}]` to be updated continuously.

```
Module[{v}, Animator@Dynamic@v]

DynamicModule[{v}, Animator@Dynamic@v]
```

The distinction seems to be that if `v` is a kernel variable, then clocks are updated continuously, but not if `v` is a front end variable.  However, this principle is not generally true, because both of the following cause the clock to be updated.

```
Module[{v = 0}, Dynamic@v++]

DynamicModule[{v = 0}, Dynamic@v++]
```

Neither of these expressions are limited by `"DynamicUpdateInterval"`, even if the kernel is fed a long computation simultaneously, which seems at odds with the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#440620996)

> By default, dynamic outputs triggered by changes in variable values are updated no faster than twenty times per second (this rate can be changed with the `SystemOption` `"DynamicUpdateInterval"`).

**Hypothesis 5** - *`Animator` is implemented in the front end*

Following up the remark by @Rojo, I noticed the following.  If you monitor CPU activity of the front end and kernel, one can see by comparing the preceding two animators that the second seems to be run entirely or almost entirely in the front end (paste several outputs to magnify the effect).  In the `Module` case, kernel usage increases as more copies of the animator are pasted, whereas in the the `DynamicModule` case, kernel usage does not change.  All forms of `Clock`, on the other hand, seem to use a small amount of kernel time.

**Concluding conjectures**

First, *`Animator` is owned by the front end and bypasses `"DynamicUpdateInterval"`, whose purpose is to limit interruptions of the kernel.*  `Animator` is represented by `AnimatorBox` in the output cell and it appears to run wholely in the front end; so it appears to be a basic element of the `Dynamic` system.  For example, it is the basis for the various `*Animate` commands.

Second, *Mathematica treats `Clock[{t1, t2, dt}]` in special way, triggering updates that are normally blocked.*  It is clear that it happens, but it is not so clear exactly how and under what conditions it happens. One question is whether the system is designed to do this.  It seems unlikely, since the behavior seems sporadic or random. Another question is whether `Animator` is designed to cause clocks to update in the observed way and why.

Third, *there is some connection between calls to the kernel and updates bypassing `"DynamicUpdateInterval"`.*  This happens when the `Animator` variable is a kernel variables, sometimes with `Clock`, and even with `Dynamic@v++` even when `v` is a `DynamicModule` variable perhaps because `Increment` is computed in the kernel.  This connection is still mysterious.

**Unresolved**

After playing around for a while, with extra dynamic clocks added and deleted for testing, `pacman` would sometimes freeze (dropped down dead drunk, I suspect).  The `Animator` would run, but `pacman` would stay at the start.  The clocks would stop, too.  Further evidence that `Animator` gets special treatment.  Quitting the kernel and reevaluating fixed this.  Also, *Mathematica* crashed on me a couple of times.

Comment: I'll look at this soon when I can. From far away it looks like the kind of answers I was hoping for :) Thanks

Comment: +1, interesting, and it triggered ideas that I'm checking out :)

Comment: About your Hypothesis 2, "sometimes the refreshed clock updates rapidly and sometimes only every 0.5 seconds. ". I can't reproduce it. Both of the two clock always refresh slowly (0.5sec per time).

Comment: @Silvia It may be system dependent.  I'm on a different machine now, and what I see is the second clock gets updated a few times quickly, but stops for a half second.  The first clock sometimes jumps ~0.5 sec, and sometimes ~1.0 sec.  I'll double-check on the other machine after I get home.  I've got v9.0.1, old macbook pro; new macbook pro at home.  There has always seemed a certain unpredictable randomness to it.  Thanks for checking.

Comment: You're welcome. I occasionally got the examples in my answer above totally "frozen". And regenerating the dynamic objects make them work again.. Frankly, I'm very confused..

Comment: btw I'm using 9.0.1 on win7 x64, with a Q6600 CPU, 8GB RAM and a nvidia 9800GTX+ graph card.

Comment: @Silvia I've gotten the frozen situation, too, and I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: AnimatorBox can be handled completely FrontEnd side, unless something complex is given inside. This can be confirmed with LinkSnooper as well as was confirmed by John Fultz. ProgressIndicator is implemented using AnimatorBoxes. Together with the fact that FE knows some arythmetic and renders graphics, makes it a powerful tool.

Answer (score 9):

I found two choices. One is to use the option `UpdateInterval -> 0` to force the update being done as fast as possible. The second is to change `Disk[{Dynamic[bla], 0}, 1, Dynamic[bla]]` in pacman definition to `Dynamic[Disk[{bla, 0}, 4, bla]]` seems to make it smoother on my *Mathematica 9*. I guess, maybe when multiple `Dynamic`s are used, they compete against each other. Or maybe *Mathematica* must choose only one `Dynamic` object to update for any one frame.

Please compare the behaviors of the following examples:

1. Using `Dynamic` on separate objects, with the default option `UpdateInterval -> ∞`

   ```
   Function[{n, r},
     Graphics[
      Map[
       Dynamic[
         Disk[
          r {Cos[2 π ((# + Clock[])/n)], 
            Sin[2 π ((# + Clock[])/n)]}, 1]
         ] &,
       Range[n]],
      PlotRange -> (r + 1) {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
     ][3, 2/Sqrt[3]]
   ```
2. Using `Dynamic` on separate objects, with the option `UpdateInterval -> 0`

   ```
   Function[{n, r},
     Graphics[
      Map[
       Dynamic[
         Disk[
          r {Cos[2 π ((# + Clock[])/n)], 
            Sin[2 π ((# + Clock[])/n)]}, 1],
         UpdateInterval -> 0] &,
       Range[n]],
      PlotRange -> (r + 1) {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
     ][3, 2/Sqrt[3]]
   ```
3. Using one `Dynamic` on the whole group of objects, with the default option `UpdateInterval -> ∞`

   ```
   Function[{n, r},
     Dynamic[Graphics[
       Map[
        Disk[
          r {Cos[2 π ((# + Clock[])/n)], 
            Sin[2 π ((# + Clock[])/n)]}, 1] &,
        Range[n]],
       PlotRange -> (r + 1) {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
      ]
     ][3, 2/Sqrt[3]]
   ```
4. Using one `Dynamic` on the whole group of objects, with the option `UpdateInterval -> 0`

   ```
   Function[{n, r},
     Dynamic[Graphics[
       Map[
        Disk[
          r {Cos[2 π ((# + Clock[])/n)], 
            Sin[2 π ((# + Clock[])/n)]}, 1] &,
        Range[n]],
       PlotRange -> (r + 1) {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}],
      UpdateInterval -> 0]
     ][3, 2/Sqrt[3]]
   ```

In my system, the last one outperforms all the others.

Comment: +1, glad you answered :). This is definately interesting and helps. I'm still wondering about the `Animator` making a difference. It even improves your last example

Comment: @Rojo Thanks :) About the mysterious `Animator`, I absolutely have no idea about why or how.. Let's wait for someone who knows something :)

Comment: @Rojo hmm.. I didn't notice any obvious difference with/without the `Animator` for the last example.. What is your mma version?

Comment: Right now I'm testing in MMA 9.0.0, in W7

Comment: @Rojo For your reference I recorded my screen with two avi size 2MB, [one with `Animator`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1em5g8wg956i1pb/with_Animator.avi), [the other without](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqg5sr699p6fi5l/without_Animator.avi).

Comment: Thanks, I'll watch it when I'm home in a few hours. Work's proxy doesn't like Dropbox, grunf

Comment: @Rojo hmm.. guess you've got something like [Great FireWall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall_of_China) too? :D

Comment: Haha. Just got home and saw the vids. I can't see any noticeable improvement in the animator version, nor I can see it testing it in my home computer. I suspect its because both versions work well enough and not because the issue was bypassed or something. You do get to see the difference in, for example, your first example (with vs without the animator)?

Comment: @Rojo Yes I do see remarkable differences in both the 1st and 2nd examples.