# How to run function every x seconds?

Tags: dynamic

I want to make a `Graphics` with a `Disk` whose position should update every 4 seconds. This is what I've got so far:

```
RunScheduledTask[(cdts = RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 2]), 4]

{Framed[Graphics[{Yellow, Disk[Dynamic@cdts, 1]}, PlotRange -> 6, 
   ImageSize -> Large]], Dynamic@cdts}
```

I chose not to use `Refresh` because that evaluates way more than once every 4 seconds (I'd say every half second or so), even though I've set `UpdateInterval-> 4`, like so:

```
{Framed[Graphics[{Yellow, 
    Disk[Dynamic@Refresh[cdts, UpdateInterval -> 4], 1]}, 
   PlotRange -> 6, ImageSize -> Large]], Dynamic@cdts}
```

From a previous question I asked, I think this is because Mathematica takes the `UpdateInterval` as a minimum, and so updates much more often when it can.

From what I've read in the documentation, `RunScheduledTask` should do exactly what I'm looking for, but it seems to update just as quickly as `Refresh`, about twice a second.

What am I doing wrong here?? I've been looking for quite a while now for a straightforward method to periodically run functions but none of them seem to work as advertised...

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem with `RunScheduledTask`.  Are you sure you do not have a couple of tasks running simultaneously?

Comment: @MichaelE2 this should be an answer :)

Comment: Your first code is fine. Dynamic updates only when the value of `cdts` is changed. Your observations are caused by not removing old `ScheduledTasks`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do what you want with a `Trigger`, which will perform real-time updates at reasonably accurate wall-clock intervals. Here is a jumping red disk that jumps every two seconds for 24 seconds.

```
center[_] := RandomReal[{-5, 5}, 2]
SeedRandom @ 42;
With[{nJumps = 12, jumpFreq = .5},
  DynamicModule[{jump = 0},
    Column[{
      Dynamic@Framed[Graphics[{Red, Disk[center[jump], .5]}, PlotRange -> 6]],
      Dynamic@Style[Row[{"Jump ", jump}], "SB"],
      Trigger[Dynamic@jump, {0, nJumps, 1}, jumpFreq, 
        AppearanceElements -> {"PlayPauseButton", "ResetButton"}]}]]]
```

[image: jumping-disk]

#### Update

In response to a request in a comment, here is more information on the arguments and option I give to `Trigger`.

`Trigger` can take anywhere from one to three arguments. To get updates at a specified wall-clock rate, all three arguments must be specified. `Trigger` has attribute `HoldFirst` and the required first argument, must always be of the form `Dynamic @ var`; `var` will receive the ticks of the trigger's clock.

The second argument specifies the sequence of tick values given to `var`. It is a list having very much the same form as the argument sequence taken by `Range`. The argument variations that can be used for `Range` can be used for this argument. In the above example, `{0, nJumps, 1}` produces the tick sequence `0, 1, 2, ..., nJumps`.

The third argument sets the clock frequency; a value of .5 Hz (as I used) is one tick every two seconds.

The standard appeareance elements for a `Trigger` are "TriggerButton", "PauseButton", and "ResetButton". The "TriggerButton" is actually a "ResetAndPlayButton". This means that a reset to zero is always performed when the "TriggerButton" is clicked, and there is no way to proceed from the paused state after the "PauseButton" is clicked. I don't like that behavior, so I used the `AppearanceElements` option to swap out the default set of controls and replace them with my own choices: "PlayPauseButton", and "ResetButton". With this set of controls, I can pause and then resume from where I paused.

Comment: That example is very useful, but could you possibly also just illustrate what Trigger does without the full example? In a fully worked example with lots of clutter it can be quite difficult to see exactly what is happening and why

Comment: @Aron. This answer is already somewhat off target because it doesn't directly answer the question asked in this thread, but suggests an alternative approach. I think this is very close to a minimal working example that is still relevant to OP's problem. I will think about how I could edit it to satisfy your request without taking it further off target.

Comment: @Aron, Update made. Hope it satisfies you.

Comment: What makes you say `Trigger` "will perform real-time updates at precise intervals"?  I think it's like most `Dynamic` things -- imprecise.

Comment: @MichaelE2. OK, I should have written (will change it to) "reasonably accurate". My example trigger ticks for 24 +/- 0.2 seconds when I time it with my mechanical Huer stopwatch.

Comment: Yes, that about what I observe.

Answer (score 2):

With `Refresh`, you need to set `TrackedSymbols :> {}`; otherwise, the displayed graphics will be updated every time a variable changes, such as `cdts` as well as every 4 seconds.

```
{Framed[Graphics[{Yellow, 
    Disk[Dynamic@
      Refresh[cdts, UpdateInterval -> 4, TrackedSymbols :> {}], 1]}, 
   PlotRange -> 6, ImageSize -> Small]], Dynamic@cdts}
```

References:

[tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality: Automatic Updates of Dynamic Objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#440620996)

[tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality: Refresh](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#1172318352)

Comment: Although I appreciate that that may help, how would that accomplish it? I want to understand why it works as well as solving the problem

Comment: @Aron The tutorials [IntroductionToDynamic](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IntroductionToDynamic.html) and [AdvancedDynamicFunctionality](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html) are pretty much the required reading for understanding `Dynamic`.  Even then, [things can seem mysterious](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15706/why-animator-smoothes-dynamic-updates-or-how-to-make-pacman-drink-beer).  In this case, however, it seems to work as described.