# How to continuously run a Python script

Tags: interoperability, python

I am running this script:

```
script = Import["!python  C:\\...python script", "String"];
```

but I need to run it a few times as it outputs data I need.  I run it every time I change something so I would like to keep it running continuously or give me a 'live' feed of changes.  I am trying to use `Dynamic`, but I am not sure how I can do it.

Edit:

My program is just a stream as I am using a sensor as a camera and the *Python* script that I run gives me the measurements that I need. The measurements change if I make the surroundings darker or lighter. Basically I'm taking pictures but I would like to be at a constant rate so it would work as a live-feed camera. Whenever I run the script it gives me different measurements so that is why I need to constantly run it but doing it manually seems like a hassle.  I would like to keep running it without me doing it.  Now I am using `RunScheduleTask` but it seems to be slow. Is there another way around this?

Comment: Take a look at `RunscheduledTask`. Related/potential duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/47263/131.

Comment: I think we need more information to help you. Do you want your python script to run at a fixed interval? Do you want it to run when you click on a button? Or do you want some other event to trigger it? Pleas do not answer these questions in a comment -- edit your question to add information about triggering the script.

Comment: `StartProcess`  might be worth a look.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  "I run it every time I change something" ... <- What do you change?  The Python script?  Do you want Mathematica to detect when the Python script has changed and re-run it automatically?

Comment: So my program is just a stream as I am using a sensor as a camera and the python script that I run gives me the measurements that I need. The measurements change if I make the surroundings darker or lighter. Basically I'm taking pictures but I would like to be at a constant rate so it would work as a live-feed camera. @Szabolcs

Comment: @m_goldberg ...

Comment: What's described in your last comment is quite different form what I *understood* from your original post.  It would be good to edit (i.e. rewrite) your original post and explain more clearly what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered using SetDelayed (:=) to define `script`?
Here is an example that is coded for Windows:

```
linPy = "'import datetime; print datetime.datetime.now()'";
winPy = "\"import datetime; print datetime.datetime.now()\"";
cmd = "!python -c " <> winPy ;
script := Import[cmd, "String"]
```

Linux users would use the "linPy" expression instead of "winPy".  With the above definitions, `script` is updated whenever it is referenced.  For example, execute the following command a few times and you will see an updated value each time:

```
First@StringTake[script, {18 ;;}]
```

Of course, you would substitute your own python command.

For a continuously updated display you could use something like the following:

```
Dynamic[x]
continueDisplay = True;
Button["Stop", continueDisplay = False]
While[continueDisplay,
 x = First@StringTake[script, {18 ;;}];
 ]
```

The While-loop will be terminated when you press the "stop" button.  The problem with continuous update is that you can't keep working in the notebook.  Using the RunScheduledTask is a better solution:

```
Dynamic[x]
delaySeconds = 2;
task = RunScheduledTask[x = First@StringTake[script, {18 ;;}], delaySeconds];
```

The scheduled task waits 2 seconds, runs the Python script and updates the displayed value of x.  It allows you to keep working in the same notebook.  To terminate the scheduled task, evaluate `RemoveScheduledTask[task];`

Comment: Yes every time I run my script I get different values but I want it so I don't have to run it manually each time.

Comment: @user35053  I have added two display methods.  One is a continuous update method and the other is an intermittent update.  Thanks for mentioning the RunScheduledTask function in your post.

Comment: the delaySeconds works! its just what I needed! Thank you~